# Microsoft.IdentityServer error trying to browse adfs/ls website

Tags: windows, adfs, adfs2.0

I'm having some issues trying to reach the adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx. I'm using windows 2012 and ADFS 2.0. The website is supposed to be configured automatically but apparently there are some features missing. I read we need to install WIF on the server but it didn't fix the error. Any help will be very much appreciate it

This is the error:

### Server Error in '/adfs/ls' Application.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityServer, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

Line 7:      
Line 8:        
Line 9:          
Line 10:         
Line 11:

Source File: C:\inetpub\adfs\ls\web.config    Line: 9

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityServer, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.6421; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.6420

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure ADFS after installing it?

After installing the ADFS role, you then need to configure it. open the ADFS MMC and it should prompt you to configure it.